# DateTime comparison failing with EF due to UTC

Tags: entity-framework, date, datetime, entity-framework-5

All times/dates in my database are stored in UTC.

Given this query

```
DateTime minus24FromUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1)
var query = from h in Context.Holidays
            where h.Date >= minus24FromUtc
            select h;
```

The following entity with a date of `3-AUG-2013 0:00:00` is ignored when `minus24FromUtc` has a value of `2-AUG-2013 2:33:29AM`.

The following comparison `query.ToArray()[0] >= minus24FromUtc` fails. I am suspecting this is because the date kind is set to `Unspecified` and as such the date is being compared to local time by mistake.

Is there a way around this with Entity Framework; I'd rather have the RDBMS handle the filtering than first get all items and set their Date Kind to UTC.

Thanks.